# Wacom CTH480 not working on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, drivers, tablet, wacom, input-devices

I have recently bought a Wacom CTH480 (Intuos pen and touch small) (I am using Ubuntu 13.04 --64 bit)

The Wacom Graphics Tablet application present under System Settings is showing "No Tablet Detected".

lsusb detects the Wacom device as connected, but

xsetwacom --list devices shows no output.

The light (white) itself on the device glows when connected to the computer and other light (blue) glows when the stylus is brought near to the active area.
The mouse pointer does not move when the stylus is moved over the active area on the tablet.

I have visited some forums discussing the problems relating Wacom tablets and the Linux Wacom project, but got nowhere on how to start troubleshooting the problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The lsusb o/p i'm getting is this:
    **BUS 004 Device 003: ID 056a:0302 Wacom Co., Ltd**

Comment: Please **edit** your question to include that information. That is how this site works - it's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, you see?

Comment: Support for the CTH480 in the linux driver only got sent to the kernel mailing list in the last two weeks. I suspect it hasn't trickled down to a released kernel/xorg driver in Ubuntu yet.